# Azure App Gateway with Internal API Management 503 backend server error

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I am following up this [doc series](https://docs.chunliu.me/apim/integration-prepare-environment.html) to set up an internal API management instance integrated with APP Gateway in `azure`. I followed everything to the detail:

1. Created a new resource group
2. Setup a Vnet with 3 subnets
3. And setup a private dns zone and link the vnet
4. And then created self-signed certificates to be used with the dns created in private dns zone
5. Created API management instance and added custom domains
6. Created a App Gateway with public IP and setup routing rules and backends and setup health probes with path `/status-0123456789abcdef` for APIM

But now I am getting this backend health error as below:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Are there any security groups to be configured? I am using an `internl` mode for the APIM, and when I even try to test the default API (which is echo test) it gives the below error:

[image]

Why this is not working? If you need any more information, I will let you know (update the question). Can someone please help me?

Comment: Anyone here to help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation which was driving me insane.  I must have changed everything I possibly could.  The answer, was to create a custom health probe and at the very bottom of the HTTP settings it was an option to use the custom probe.

Comment: Yes, all works great, when you know the default probe is not the one you create and is pretty rubbish and provides little useful feedback other than it isn't working.  Assigning my custom probe by name as above fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Gateway URL is not registered on the public DNS, the test console available on the Azure portal will not work for Internal VNET deployed service. Instead, use the test console provided on the Developer portal.
You can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet).

Comment: No, I am trying to access the echo test api from the API management, not from the app gateway. The traffic flows from `app gateway` --> `apim` ---> `backend configured in the apim`. Forget the `app gateway` i should be able to connect to the echo test backend api from the `apim` right?

Comment: Hi, how can I access developer portal? now that the APIM is internal, how can I access it?